# Selenium Java - Cant fill List<WebElement> from Table

Tags: java, html, selenium

I got a problem with fill List from table:

```
 <div class="es">
<button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['add']">New User</button>

 </div>
<div class="User_table" id="t02" >
  <div class="table" id="t01" >
    <div class="table-row table-header">
         <div class="table-row-item"> <span>Number</span><span></span></div>
      <div class="table-row-item userimg"></div>
      <div class="table-row-item u-flex-grow4"><span>Name</span><span ></span></div>
      <div class="table-row-item  u-flex-grow4"><span>Rights</span><span ></span></div>
      <div class="table-row-item  u-flex-grow4"><span>Registered</span><span "></span></div>
      <div class="table-row-item u-flex-grow4"><span>Property management</span></div>

    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let data of User; let i = index" class="table-row">
      <div class="table-row-item" data-header="Number">{{i + 1}}</div>
      <div class="table-row-item userimg"><img [class]="(data?.image ? '' : 'default')" [src]="data?.img_src" alt= "Profil"/></div>
      <div class="table-row-item u-flex-grow4" data-header="Name">{{data?.fName}} {{data?.lName}}</div>
      <div class="table-row-item u-flex-grow4" data-header="Rights">{{data?.role}}</div>
      <div class="table-row-item u-flex-grow4" data-header="Registered">{{data?.firstTimeLogin | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</div>
      <div class="table-row-item u-flex-grow4" data-header="Property management">{{data?.PropertyIds?.length}}<a [routerLink]="['edit', data.id]"><span class="i_edit"></span></a></div>
  <!--     routerLink="/Profil/{{ data['id']}}" routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" -->
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I tried by Id and Xpath to fill my List but nothing was working, like

```
 List<WebElement> TotalRowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"t01\"]"));
```

or

```
 List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.className("table-row"));
```

I am using Developer Tools for read Xpath or others like cssSelector but nothing is working. Any ideas ?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Not error, cant fill the List, its empty

Comment: How do you want to fill up the `List`? What is the expected data within the `List`?

Comment: If you want to list the items in the table, have you tried to find it by className = "table-row-item" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to generate a `List` of the *WebElements* with texts such as **Name**, **Rights**, **Registered** and **Property management** you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> TotalRowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='table' and @id='t01']//div[@class='table-row-item u-flex-grow4']//following::span[1]"));
```